# ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading authorization packet', system error: 95

Tags: mysql-5.7

I am upgrading from MySQL 5.7.33 to MySQL 5.7.37 on a CentOS 7 server.  For a minor upgrade, I normally accomplish this by removing the old binaries, replacing them with the new binaries, restarting mysqld and then logging in. However, my login fails with this error:
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading authorization packet', system error: 95
I have seen some discussion about the problem on the internet, but have seen no usable solution.  I understand the problem started with MySQL 5.7.34. Has anyone seen a solution to this problem? If you have, please, send me the link. if I add the following statement to my my.cnf file, I am able to login --skip-grant-tables This not a solution but it narrows the problem down to some change in the authentication process between version 5.7.33 and 5.7.34.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Please put any extra information into the question itself rather than in comments - it's easier to read that way!

Comment: Please consider posting TEXT results of A) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout%'; and B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'aborted%';  for consideration.  How long does it usually take for this error message to be displayed?

Comment: connect_timeout=10
delayed_insert_timeout=300
have_statement_timeout=YES
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout=1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=50
innodb_rollback_on_timeout=OFF
interactive_timeout=28800
lock_wait_timeout=31536000 |
net_read_timeout=30
net_write_timeout=60
rpl_stop_slave_timeout=31536000
slave_net_timeout=60
wait_timeout=28800

Comment: Aborted_clients=4 
Aborted_connects=60

Comment: The response time is instantaneous although using "time mysql -ufurlongs -" shows 7.5s.

Comment: Wilson Hauck, this post looked promising, but had no solution.  https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?132,696220,696220

Comment: I am currently using mysql_native_password.  I am going to switch to sha256_password to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I don't quite understand the whys behind it, but this solution appears to be working.  https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?35,703715,703812#msg-703812

Comment: This problem was solved at this url      https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?35,703715